# Manipulating a char by ascii number

Tags: c, char, int, ascii

I want to change a char using ascii values.

So far I have this:

```
unsigned char invertChar(char c){

    unsigned char y;
    printf("255 - %d=", c);
    y = 255 - (int)c;
    printf("%d\n", y);
    return y;

}
```

////EDIT.

So far so good but I've encountered another problem.

```
int main(void){
char source[10]; //Has info.
char invertedBuffer[10];
unsigned char help;
int counter;


for(counter = 0; counter<10; counter++){
help = invertChar(source[counter]);
 invertedBuffer[counter] = help;
  printf("Inverted Char: %u\n", invertedBuffer[counter]);

}
```

The problem is that when I do printf, I get this(on all of my prints):

```
Inverted Char: 4294967194
```

Thank you for your time and expertise.

Comment: Use `unsigned char` instead of `char` and `%u` instead of `%d`.

Comment: @DoxyLover so y is unsigned?

Comment: `signed char` has a range of -128 to +127. Obviously, you cannot represent 255 or 223 in this range. `unsigned char` has a range of 0 to 255.

Comment: @DoxyLover thank you, I'm learning as I go. You help me solve the problem inside my function but what about it when I call it in my main?
Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Same issue: since invertChar is a signed char, it will be sign-extended to a negative integer, which, when printed with %u, will result in 2^32-x.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker invertChar is an unsigned char. isnt it? and the help variable is also unsigned.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the invertedBuffer[] array. It's still signed.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Oh, thank you very much! I forgot that must be changed as well!
my issue is officially closed. Is it possible you post this as an answer, I'll give you my upvote. :D

Comment: One note: The standard makes no guarantees that the character set is ASCII. It *usually* is nowadays, at least on consumer hardware; certain IBM mainframes use EBCDIC, for example. There are pretty much only two guarantees in the standard: 1) `'\0'` ends the string, and 2) `0123456789` are together in a sequence.

Comment: @TimČas what do you mean with 'standard'??

Comment: @Dro: Any C standard. C89, C99 or C11. In other words, you cannot rely on the strings to be in a specific encoding (assuming you're writing portable code).

Answer (score 0):

since the invertedBuffer[] array is a signed char, it will be sign-extended to a negative integer, which, when printed with %u, will result in 2^32-x. –  Lee Daniel Crocker